# Am I concentrating these character arrays incorrectly?

Tags: c++, filestream

I've been trying to create a midi file from scratch with c++. I'm separating different chunks(and parts of chunks) into different character arrays.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int, char* []) {
    std::ofstream MIDIfile ("example.mid")
    char header[] = { /* hex data */ };
    char track_header[] = { /* hex data */ };
    char track_data[] = { /* hex data */ };
    MIDIfile << strcat(header, strcat(track_header, track_data));
    MIDIfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My only problem is that when the file is written, only 8 of the 81 bytes are written. Is there a reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Regards, shadowstalker75

Comment: Don't post images. Do post code here.

Comment: Please post your code as `formatted text`.

Comment: There's an option for images so I thought it would be appropriate. I'll edit it now.

Comment: If you're programming with C++, why are you using plain `char` arrays and `strcat`? Why not use `std::string` properly instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, as far as I know MIDI data are not strings but binary, so it's not evident that `std::string` could be used.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Seeing `char` arrays and using string functions, then the natural conclusion is usually strings. In this case perhaps `std::array<int8_t, X>` could be better? Or if concatenating then perhaps using `std::vector<int8_t>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I totally agree, with C++11 you can even initialize a vector with a `{...}` block. However, people who are new to C++ don't learn STL on day one. It takes a little time.

Comment: What is the [int8_t] variable type?

Comment: @shadow_stalker75 A signed integer that is guarateed to be 8 bits in size. Possible values range from -127 through 128 for a 2's complement system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to learn what `strcat()` does. This line is never going to work. Actually, even better, NEVER USE `strcat()`. It's crap.

```
MIDIfile << strcat(header, strcat(track_header, track_data));
```

You have binary buffers of hex data, just use the `write()` function:

```
MIDIfile.write(header, sizeof(header));
...
```

and write one buffer at a time.

Comment: Why is it bad to use strcat?

Comment: There is no buffer size check. And `strncat()` is totally broken too. The `n` is not the total size of the destination buffer. I'm not too sure who was the guy who invented those two functions, but he should have been killed before it happened. It has caused a HUGE number of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The [formatted `operator<<` function for `char` arrays or pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is for printing ***null-terminated*** strings. If your "hex data" contains any zeroes (binary zeroes, `0`, not the character `'0'`) then that will act as the terminator.

That's not to mention the buffer overflows you have, since you append into a fixed-sized array which is specifically sized for the data you initialize it with.

The solution is first of all not to use arbitrary binary data as strings (the `strcat` function *also* expects the data to be null-terminated strings) but as raw data. Secondly you need to use [the `write` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to write arbitrary data.